# Select only elements that don't have a parent with defined class

Tags: css, css-selectors

How do I select only children that don't have a parent with a certain class in their parent tree?

This didn't work:

```
div:not(.dontSelect) .child
```

```css
div {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 5px;
}

div:not(.dontSelect) .child {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="child">
    Select this
  </div>
  <div class="dontSelect">
    <div>
      <div class="child">
        Don't select this
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you want the `child` element to be styled with the green `background`?

Comment: @PatrickMcDermott yes, but only the first, cause the other has a parent that I don't like ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can use combinator selectors with `:not` as [stated in the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anot):

> This selector only applies to one element; you cannot use it to
>   exclude all ancestors. For instance, `body :not(table) a` will still
>   apply to links inside of a table, since `<tr>` will match with the
>   `:not()` part of the selector.

You could try something like this:

```css
div {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 5px;
}

.child {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 5px;
}

.dontSelect .child {
  background-color: initial;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="child">
    Select this
  </div>
  <div class="dontSelect">
    <div>
      <div class="child">
        Don't select this
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you explain, why not() can't be used?

Comment: Unfortunately it's just not supported. You can read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anot

Comment: I see, they denied exactly what I was trying to do, I added it to your response.

Answer (score 13):

As mentioned before, you cannot use `:not()` to exclude ancestors in combination selectors, but can target your .child class and exclude elements with a specific parent:

```
.child:not(.dontSelect .child){
    background-color: green;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a `id` for main `div`:

```css
div#content {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 5px;
}

div#content > div:not(.dontSelect).child {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div class="child">
    Select this
  </div>
  <div class="dontSelect">
    <div>
      <div class="child">
        Don't select this
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```